# How to disable tracking changes within editor of Rider?

Tags: c#, settings, rider

When Rider detects you are using some version control it will show for example gray triangles next to line numbers in places when some code was removed (within the editor).

How to disable this feature?

*I checked settings with phrase "track changes" but I found nothing relevant. Maybe it is named differently.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this area of the editor is called Gutter
Go to File > Settings > search for Gutter
and you will be able to disable it look picture
[image]